# Unable to get events in Polygon's test network

Tags: web3js, events, polygon

I want to get the address of an event for a contract I created in mumbai test network, but I get the following error

```
Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "Blockheight too far in the past: eth_getLogs. Range of blocks allowed for your plan: 1000",
  "code": -32005
}
```

I tried this.

```
const polygonContractAddress = 'CONTRACT_ADDRESS';
const polygonTokenContract = new polygonWeb3.eth.Contract(
  CreateTokenPolygonJson.abi,
  polygonContractAddress,
);

const txs = await polygonTokenContract.getPastEvents('Mint', {
  filter:{tokenId: '2'},
  fromBlock: 0,
  toBlock: 'latest',
})
console.log(txs,"txs")
```

I could get events in rinkeby test newwork.
How can I get it ?

I don't get a meaning of "your plan".

Answer (score 1):

You get that because of `fromBlock: 0`. It's telling you that your 'plan' only allows you to retrieve 1000 blocks but from 0 to the latest is more than 1000. I was confused too... perhaps Polygon has different plans for different types of users. I couldn't find any documentation on this.

What I did was get the current block using `web3.eth.getBlockNumber`, then when that returns set the option `fromBlock: currentBlock - 50`

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be about both the network you're working on (Mumbai testnet / Polygon mainnet) and the API URL limitations.

I was using the free version of the QuickNode API URL and I was working on the Mumbai testnet. After changing the API to Alchemy and the network to Goerli, everything started to work normally. (By the way, I was using the `thirdweb-dev/sdk` package to deploy and work with my contract, but it's not different from implementing the contract using Solidity)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe very late since the date you pose this question but I had this problem too.

I am using metamask and the issue is the rpcUrl in it.

I was using https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com, which maticvigil have tier plans. So I switch to Alchemy rpc url in network settings in metamask and it work with `fromBlock: 0`.